# passing this to methods in jQuery when using prototyping of methods

Tags: jquery, binding, methods, this, prototyping

I'm using a code like the following

```
function Basket () {
  this.items = new Array();
}
Basket.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
  setTimeout(this.showItems, 1000);
};
Basket.prototype.showItems = function() {
  console.log('items in Basket: '+this.items.join(', '));
}

var b = new Basket()
b.addItem('bananas')
// -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined
```

When calling the addItem method, the showItems method is called properly, but in the showItems method the variable "this" does not reference to the Basket object.
Using the Prototype framework I could do something like

```
setTimeout(this.showItems.bind(this), 1000)
```

This would bind the variable "this" to the Basket object in the showItems method.

Question: How can I achieve that in jQuery? Is there a more elegant method (best practice) than wrapping the calling method like so:

```
// ...
  $this = this
  setTimeout(function() {$this.showItems($this)}, 1000)

Basket.prototype.showItems = function ($this) {
  console.log('items in Basket: '+$this.items.join(', '));
}
```

I would also be happy, if someone could post some useful keywords, how I could search for that sort of problems, as I'm sure, I'm not the only one asking this. But naturally it is very hard to search for "prototype" when you don't have the framework in mind, but the extension of objects (or how you call it).

thx

Comment: naturally this a a small example. I want to use that in something like this.somejqueryobject.scroll(this.someMethod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, jQuery offers a `$.proxy` method which has the same functionality as the `bind` provided by Prototype.

There is a documentation page available at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/.

Hope that helps,
Dave

Comment: Thx Dave. It seems it's doing what I want.

Comment: Just to be specific: The timeout line would look like this with the proxy method: `setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(this.showItems,this), 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

why not simply add the methods to Basket?

```
function Basket () {
  var items = new Array();
  this.addItem = function(item) {
     items.push(item);
     setTimeout(this.showItems, 1000);
   };
   this.showItems = function() {
      console.log('items in Basket: '+ items.join(', '));
   };
};
```

Comment: I used to write code like this, but using prototyping you can save memory, if you have a lot of Basket objects. Why? Because with code like this one you register two methods when generating a new Basket. If you use prototyping only two methods/function will be registered in the memory which will be used by all Basket objects. So this code is OK if you have only a small count of objects, while my version above is good, when you have lots of objects. At least this is what I [read at this blogpost](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/).

Comment: @beipawel when was the last time your JavaScript had a memory usage problem? Sounds a lot like premature optimisation. You are trading encapsulation for fixing a usually non existing problem